# Any negative impact of new Charset handling in Spring Framework 4.3.x?

Tags: java, spring

Recently upgraded to Spring 4.3.x from 4.2.x.  Noticed one change in the HTTP headers.  The only documentation I found was this under "Web Improvements":

```
Consistent charset handling in HTTP message converters, including a UTF-8 default for multipart text content.
```

Can anyone provide additional information?  Two specific questions: 1. any possible negative impacts, and 2. examples of using non-UTF-8 charsets.

Comment: The two things that you list are not "*specific* items"

Comment: point taken - thanks!